# Embed a link within the Image

Tags: images

How can I embed a 3rd party link within an image which is automatically called once the image is opened through a web browser or website?
The link literally calls out everytime the image is refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible.

Images *themselves* cannot contain links. At least none of the common bitmap-based image formats have any way to embed this kind of information. In principle, [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) allows you to embed URLs, but those are not hyperlinked. Because image formats are not interactive.

After all, what you describe would also be a huge security concern. Much like [tracking images used for e-mail marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_tracking), having an image automatically open a URL in a browser would be considered intrusive behavior, as opening a URL also automatically means you're exposing your IP address, its associated geolocation, and browser fingerprint to the server.

No operating system vendor, or developer of image viewers, browsers, etc. would implement something like this.

You can of course implement a simple JavaScript that opens another location in the browser, but that requires you to embed the image in HTML.